# What are the conditions to make height: 100%; display properly?

Tags: css

I never had to use this, but sometimes it comes handy... when it works.

Whenever I write the code, sometimes happens that `height: 100%;` works, and sometimes doesn't.

Why this happens? I suspect I have to edit some other properties, but which?

Comment: It normally happens because the DIV is nested inside of something that is NOT set to 100%, so it can only fill the available area.  But this is likely irrelevant since you never use it.

Comment: it works if the parent container has height applied to it or inherited from above elements.

Comment: ask yourself this question: "100% of what?" see, for some elements, 100% is the size of its child elements, and for some its the size of the container. it depends on the positioning (relative/absolute) and on whether or not you set height to the relevant elements. probably depends on other things too, which slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from w3c, here's their definition:

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the
>   root element is relative to the initial containing block. Note: For
>   absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a
>   block-level element, the percentage is calculated with respect to the
>   height of the padding box of that element. This is a change from CSS1,
>   where the percentage was always calculated with respect to the content
>   box of the parent element.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height

Basically it will take 100% of the height available to it. If the element it is within has a height of 100px, then it will be 100% of 100px. Thus 100px.

If the element with `height:100%` has `position:absolute` then it will mean it takes the height of the closest parent element with `position:relative` or else the height of the visible window.

---

As pointed out in another answer. This only applies to block elements (or those with `display:block` applied to them).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you observe "*sometimes height: 100%; works, and sometimes doesn't*" depending on the type of element? **Inline** elements, such as `<span>`, `<b>`, `<abbr>` and so on does not have `height` or `width`. See this example :

```css
body {
    height : 400px;
}
span {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

and the result -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Ykca3/**
even though the `<span>` is set to `height:100%`, and its parent have a fixed height, it is not rendered as with 100% height.